# How to fire update progress in child update panel?

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, updatepanel

I have nested update panel and both have their own update progress. Now when I click on button inside the child update panel then also the update progress of the parent is triggered.

How to fix this ?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelParent" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            ...
            ... some controls
            ...
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelChild" runat="server" >
                <ContentTemplate>
                    ...
                    ... some controls
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgressChild" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanelChild" DisplayAfter="0">
                <ProgressTemplate>    
                    Updating child...
                </ProgressTemplate>
                </asp:UpdateProgress>


        </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>    
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgressParent" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanelParent" DisplayAfter="0">
    <ProgressTemplate>    
        Updating parent...
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to modify your design as 2 separate Update panels as below, instead of nesting them.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelParent" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblParent" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Button ID="btnParent" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnParent_Click" />
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnParent" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelChild" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblChild" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Button ID="btnChild" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnChild_Click" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgressChild" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanelChild"
            DisplayAfter="0">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                Updating child...
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgressParent" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanelParent"
            DisplayAfter="0">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                Updating parent...
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Since `UpdatePanelParent` is made `UpdateMode="Conditional"`, it get updated only when the specified `Trigger` from the control is made and the `UpdatePanelChild` will get updated all the time. Hence maintaining the expected output, i hope.